# Install PostgreSQL extension for non-superuser

Tags: postgresql, permissions, superuser, pgcrypto, postgresql-extensions

My app's database has a dedicated user with full access like so;

```
CREATE DATABASE "mydb"
  WITH OWNER = cloudsqlsuperuser
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "mydb" TO public;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "mydb" TO cloudsqlsuperuser;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "mydb" TO "mydb";
```

In the startup of my app I have the following query in place to make sure that UUID extension is available;

```
create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp";
```

This works great. However I recently tried adding an identical query to create "pgcrypto" extension like so;

```
create extension if not exists "pgcrypto";
```

This fails claiming I need super user privileges to create the extension. So I decided to manually create it as a superuser user. However even if I log as postgres user in Adminer and create the extension successfully, it does not become available to the queries in my app (mydb user).

I am not familiar with the namespace mechanisms used in PostgreSQL, so I want to know **how can I  create the extension so that it will become available from my app's code without giving app user superuser privileges?**

Comment: "*and create the extension successfully,*" - are you sure you connect to the same database as your `app`? The create extension needs to be run in every database where you want to use it

Comment: `\dx` in `psql` will tell you in which schema the extension is installed.

Comment: It seems I was indeed connected to the wrong database. Connecting to the correct database with a super user before installing the extension solved my problem. Thanks!